# Failing Vercel deploy with error TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at multiple objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my webapp for the first time and I'm getting this error on Vercel:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
> at Object.3qS3 (/vercel/path0/.next/serverless/pages/[collection]/[templateId].js:2510:16)

I'm recieving the error regarding multiple objects. I believe this is what's causing the issue:

```
  const balanceAmount = parseFloat(
    currentUserBalance.split(' ')[0].replace(/[,]/g, '')
  );
```

I don't understand what's causing the issue.

Edit. I tried adding the following conditional statement before:

```
 if (currentUserBalance == undefined) {
    currentUserBalance === '1';
  }
```

it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const balanceAmount = parseFloat(
    currentUserBalance?.split(' ')[0]?.replace(/[,]/g, '')
  );
```

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it but it's still giving me the same error on deployment.

Comment: Can you see the full code